# Storing each checked radio button value from HTML table to an array in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code in HTML  tag

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="s1" value="1" checked/>
            <input type="radio" name="s1" value="0"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="s2" value="1"/>
            <input type="radio" name="s2" value="0" checked/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How to get each checked value from every row in a table using JQuery/Javascript and store it into an array.

For Example: In above case I should get **1,0**

Comment: There are multiple simple ways to accomplish this easy task. What have you tried?

Comment: @cookiemonster Check this http://jsfiddle.net/7KNV5/

Comment: @cookiemonster Can I see any of your simple method or tell me how can i select checked radio in http://jsfiddle.net/7KNV5/

Comment: You were shown below, but `$("table input:checked").map(funcion(i, el) { return this.value }).toArray();` is one way. And it doesn't even need to be that complex. If you know how to select inputs, and if you know how to use a for loop and look up properties on an element, you can do this. These are basic, fundamental things that should be learned in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

```
var array = []; 
$('input:checked').each(function(){
    array.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: `.map` should be used for case like that.

Comment: @dbucki How would you check for input:checked in a situation like this http://jsfiddle.net/7KNV5/